# C and C++ header: Define global struct inside of another struct

Tags: c++, c, interop

I have some C code that has some structs that looks like this:

```cpp
typedef struct my_library_a_t my_library_a_t;
typedef struct my_library_b_t my_library_b_t;
typedef struct my_library_c_t my_library_c_t;

struct my_library_a_t {
    struct my_library_b_t {
        int data;
        struct my_library_c_t {
            int data;
        } c;
    } b;
    int data;
};
```

This doesn't work in C++, because in C `struct my_library_b_t` defines a global `struct my_library_b_t`, whereas in C++ it defines `::my_library_a_t::my_library_b_t`.

How can I get the inner struct definition to define a global struct in C++? Or even just not have to change too much code for it to work (I don't mind having a `#ifdef __cplusplus` block, but I don't want to pull the structs out because the reason they are nested in the first place is that they are used only one time each, and it's really hard to read when the inner class definitions are above the outer class definitions)

I tried `struct ::my_library_b_t` in the definition, but this doesn't work.

For context, I'm parsing a string that has a definition that would look like this:

```cpp
a     = b "," data
b     = data "," c
c     = data
data  = %x31-39 *DIGIT  ; 1-9 followed by *(0-9)
      / "0"
```

And the intermediate parts have meaning, so it's useful to be able to have functions that take `my_library_b_t*` or `my_library_c_t*`.

I would prefer to have a solution that looks like this:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define GLOBAL_STRUCT(name) ???  (I tried `:: name`)
extern "C" {
#else
#define GLOBAL_STRUCT(name) name
#endif

struct my_library_a_t {
    struct GLOBAL_STRUCT(my_library_b_t) {
// ...
```

Comment: May be you'd better not compile with code with C++ compiler? This looks like one of the not so many examples when C++ compiler should not be used to compile C headers. I believe your problem does not have a solution in C++. No matter what you do, a nested type in C++ will be a nested type, and will never become global.

Comment: By the way, I wonder why this question was downvoted. It is a valid question, even if it doesn't seem to have a solution.

Comment: The only way to fix it sanely is to make the nested declaration in C non-nested.  The local rules for your C code headers that have to be usable from C++ says "though shalt not define a structure or union (or enumeration) type within another structure or union type definition" — I don't think you can nest type definitions within an enumeration, so that problem doesn't arise.

Comment: Don't use global variables.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this

```
struct my_library_a_t {
    struct my_library_b_t {
        int data;
        struct my_library_c_t {
            int data;
        } c;
    } b;
    int data;
};
#ifdef __cplusplus
    typedef struct my_library_a_t::my_library_b_t my_library_b_t;
    typedef struct my_library_b_t::my_library_c_t my_library_c_t;
#else
    typedef struct my_library_a_t my_library_a_t;
    typedef struct my_library_b_t my_library_b_t;
    typedef struct my_library_c_t my_library_c_t;
#endif
```

Notice that after alias my_library_b_t, you don't need to use my_library_a_t::my_library_b_t::my_library_c_t